# Is there a word, slang that means "something that stops conversation"?

Tags: word-request

Looking for something with a negative connotation. The only thing I can think of is "conversation-killer", but that's not idiomatic, and I've never heard someone use it. I am pretty sure there must be something, a word, maybe. If you can't think of a word, can you think of an idiom or coined phrase?

For example:

> That was a real ___, it completely shut us up.

Comment: Bombshell? Zinger? Show-stopper?

Comment: What if you're looking for a word that implies something negative.

Comment: @frbsfok I have something for a negative, but you should edit your question to include that as a requirement.

Comment: There is "the remark went down like a lead balloon" (as in the metal lead) but the usage is more general than killing a conversation.

Comment: Before the referendum, I was in a shared taxi in Spain with a middle class British couple from Kent, I think they thought I was like them. I incautiously said "If you want to know which way to vote on Brexit, you just have to look at the people who support it". If there had been a thermometer in the vehicle, the mercury would have plunged. Eventually, the wife, coolly, but with the hint of a mischievous smile, said "What do you mean?" and I hastily said, "Well, Michael Gove is a toad of a man, and as for Farage...". She grinned at me in such a way that her husband could not see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "conversation-stopper" is an expression for that kind of thing. Embarrassment and shock are pretty negative where I come from.

> conversation-stopper
>
> noun [ C usually singular ] ​ a remark that stops the natural flow of
>   the conversation because it is unexpected and in some way causes
>   embarrassment or shock:
>
> *When she told us her son was in prison, it was a real conversation-stopper.*

[Conversation-stopper (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conversation-stopper)

Answer (score 1):

For slang, there is [**buzzkill**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buzzkill):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : one that has a depressing or negative effect
>
> // Skyler became a *buzzkill*, and that pissed viewers off.
>   — Anne T. Donahue, *Marie Claire*, "Even If You Hated Skyler White on Breaking Bad, She Changed TV Forever," 9 Aug. 2018
>
> // And, not to be a total *buzzkill*, but there are only stores in New Jersey, New York, Maryland, and Massachusetts at the moment.
>   — Danielle Tullo, *House Beautiful*, "8 Things You Should Know Before Shopping at Homesense," 3 Aug. 2018

In the example sentence:

> That was a real buzzkill, it completely shut us up.